# Jnuit testing from public to private methods

Tags: java, junit

I have a public method to test which calls a private method. This private method in turn calls a db using a variable that's provided from the public method. While unit testing I provide a dummy variable data to the public method, but its breaking as no record can be pulled from database with that dummy variable. How do I handle this? Right now, we have a try catch block for that private method call and the test always fails. As long as it doesn't give an error, we are passing the test. Is that right approach?

I apologize if it doesn't make much sense, I am rather new to unit testing. Thanks.

Comment: That seems like more of an integration test than a unit test.

Comment: If you want to do that, provide the database connection via a parameter to the method and provide it an in-memory database object (as long as your database supports in-memory) Apart from that, can you please add how your private method accesses the connection to the DB? A public static field, or what? Please share some code.

Comment: Please share the code so that you can get answers that really help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should mock the results from the database request. After all, a test should not be aware of the data in your DB.

[Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) can help you there.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use an in-memory database like H2,and populate it before the test with the required data. You could use something like DBUnit to populate it.

These tests wouldn't be as unitary, but you could still use jUnit to do them.